# How to check aws ec2 is running or not using aws lambda (boto3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, java-web-start

I want to know whether my instance is in running state or not, if its in running state then only file will get copied from s3 into my ec2 instance and then file will run in that machine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please clarify your question? Are you simply wanting to find out how to check the state of the EC2 instance, or are you also asking how to copy a file to it and then run something on that instance? Please Edit your question and provide as much information as possible so that you get a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query of [instance "state" attribute](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.state).

For example: `instance.state['Name']`

This returns a state string, example `stopped`

Possible states are:

> 0 : pending   16 : running  32 : shutting-down   48 : terminated   64
>   : stopping   80 : stopped

And here is [Python code example](https://gist.github.com/dastergon/b4994c605f76d528d0c4) to retrieve EC2 instance information.

Comment: Any idea where to get this as a dict from either boto3 or botocore?  I hate writing code comparing strings against "running".  It's error prone.  I'd rather write it comparing against boto3.something.ec2states.running.  At least there if I put a single n in running instead of 2 I'll get an attribute error.  If I compare strings the code will run just fine and it'll look like nothing is running.