# Lamda function failed to stop ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have created Lambda Function to stop EC2 instances. Its perfectly working fine. However, I discovered that the lambda function does not halt EC2 instances on Fridays, although it does it correctly on other weekdays. I'm not sure why it failed to shut down EC2 instances solely on Friday. Even i had a look at the cloudwatch log groups. Log seems Lambda function stopped the ec2 instances on last friday.
Is it feasible to get a notification when EC2 instances running after a certain amount of time? Because if lambda fails to stop the EC2 instances, I'd prefer to manually stop them.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't provided any logs. Do the log say why the instaces were not being shutdown? You can make an alarm for the lambda by the way if there are errors it can send you an email.

Comment: Log says, its stopped the ec2 instances. But Instances were running on that time.

Comment: In that case you can create a lambda which checks the state of all the EC2 instances. You can schedule this lambda to run 10/15 min after your stop instances lambda function. Another way of stopping the instance at a schedule is using cloudwatch events. If you do not have a lot of instances to stop, you can make a rule which can stop the instances for you at the particular time.

Comment: Good point. Is possible to send mail notification when ec2 instance not stopped after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Yes sure, you can add an sns in destination for the lambda which checks all the intances' state. For the lambda you can check https://youtu.be/Nni_8TUI_zA (not a very good tutorial but can be a help) and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309077/how-to-check-aws-ec2-is-running-or-not-using-aws-lambda-boto3

Comment: this might help: https://medium.com/geekculture/terraform-setup-for-automatically-turning-off-ec2-instances-upon-inactivity-d7f414390800

Answer (score 0):

I think You can refer to this doc here - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-email-instance-state-change/

What they are doing is

1. Creating an SNS topic that you will have to subscribe to with your email or HTTP API. If there are any notifications, they will be sent to the subscribed entities.
2. Creating an Event Bridge (This functionality earlier used to be clubbed with CloudWatch as event rules, now I think its a separate service)

Essentially, Even Bridge will listen for an EC2 state change. In your case, I think it would be from RUNNING to STOPPING/STOPPED.
As the Event Bridge rule matches, it will trigger an SNS notification.

So, you will get the notification with all the instance ids that have been stopped.

Conversely, you can perhaps run a Lambda on Friday late night using EventBridge Schedule to run a Lambda that does a DescribeInstances API and lists all the instances that are still running.